# Replace all NAs or "N/A" values in a dataset with the mean of every column they exist

Tags: r

In the dataframe below which has columns with only numeric values I want to find the `NAs` or "N/A" of every column and replace them with the mean value of the rest of the rows of each column

```
data <- structure(list(`Review Star` = c("N/A", "5", "5", "4", NA, "5", 
"3.4", NA), `Total Review` = c("N/A", "1", "5", "5", NA, "1", 
"5", NA)), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))

library(dplyr)
data <- data %>% 
  mutate_all(~ifelse(. %in% c("N/A", "NA"), mean(., na.rm = TRUE), .))
```

Comment: your example data is strings, there are no numbers involved. do you need help turning strings to numbers as a first step ?

Comment: Replace `"N/A"` with `NA` first, then do the mean replacement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `zoo` package has an `na.aggregate` function for this very purpose ("Replace NA by Aggregation"). Since you have a character `"N/A"`, you'd need to convert your data to numeric using `as.numeric`, which will default the character `"N/A"` to `NA`:

```
zoo::na.aggregate(apply(data, 2, as.numeric))

#      Review Star Total Review
# [1,]        4.48          3.4
# [2,]        5.00          1.0
# [3,]        5.00          5.0
# [4,]        4.00          5.0
# [5,]        4.48          3.4
# [6,]        5.00          1.0
# [7,]        3.40          5.0
# [8,]        4.48          3.4
```

Or alternatively using `sapply` and specifying the specific columns:

```
zoo::na.aggregate(sapply(data[c("Review Star", "Total Review")], as.numeric))
```

Comment: Why using `apply` on a data.frame? `sapply` is the better choice. Also better show `data[1:2]` to indicate columns should be selected.

Comment: The point is that using `apply` on data.frames is very inefficient in contrast to `lapply` or `sapply`, they only sound similar `apply` is designed for matrices. +1 anyway

Answer (score 2):

This is how I would do it in one go in `dplyr`. Using `type.convert` to convert to numeric easily and then `mutate` + `replace`.

```r
library(dplyr)
type.convert(data, as.is = TRUE) |> 
  mutate(across(everything(), \(x) replace(x, is.na(x), mean(x, na.rm = TRUE))))

#   Review Star Total Review
# 1        4.48          3.4
# 2           5            1
# 3           5            5
# 4           4            5
# 5        4.48          3.4
# 6           5            1
# 7         3.4            5
# 8        4.48          3.4
```

---

Or in combination with `imputeTS::na_mean` or `zoo::na.aggregate`:

```r
imputeTS::na_mean(type.convert(data, as.is = TRUE))
zoo::na.aggregate(type.convert(data, as.is = TRUE))
```

Answer (score 1):

Staying close to your original solution you had a few issues:

1. Your numbers are strings - fix using `as.numeric`
2. You need to use `is.na()` to find NAs because the "NA" string does not equate to NA
3. Using the tilda `~` function requires use of `.x` annotation instead of `.`

So the solution looks like this:

```
data <- data %>% 
  mutate_all(~ifelse(.x %in% c("N/A")|is.na(.x), mean(as.numeric(.x), na.rm = TRUE), .x))
```

Comment: Great points! Though I prefer `.x` for readability, I dont think your last point is true, you can use `.` with no issues - try running `data %>% mutate(across(everything(), ~paste0(., "_test")))` and it works fine.

Comment: It doesn't work with the code I posted

Comment: yes, it does for me - perhaps it's a version thing (v1.1.2)